# Routing is not working correct for my vue app deployed in service fabric wwwroot folder

Tags: vue-router, azure-service-fabric

Recently I am trying to deploy a vue page to my service fabric cluster application. The way I did was to build the vue app, get the vue.app file and index.html file, then copy to the wwwroot folder of my service fabric application. The problem when visiting https://xxx.trafficmanager.net/#/ I will get 404, and the only way I can visit the site is to use https://xxx.trafficmanager.net/index.html. Also, the routing works fine when debug locally, I can use https://localhost/#/ to visit my vue app.

Hope you have some insights for this issue

Answer (score 0):

After some research and investigation I found that in service fabric cluster I accidentally placed usestaticfile before usedefaultfiles, see this post: [Why does order between UseStaticFiles and UseDefaultFiles matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53988848/why-does-order-between-usestaticfiles-and-usedefaultfiles-matter/53989035)
UseDefaultFiles place as a url rewrite here which can help resolve this issue